# New - Unresolved reference: kotlinx

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

although:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
```

is already stated in the project build.gradle file

using Android Studio 2.1.3

Kotlin plugin version 1.0.3

target SDK version is 24

minimum SDK version is 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Solved this problem, Im not reading the Kotlin manual.

Comment: so problem is solved, right?